# Why is my JSON fetch query returning undefined values?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to find some specific data from a JSON file using the fetch query, my code so far looks like this:

```
function newfuntion() {
    var my_list = []
    fetch("url")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            x= data.mydata.filter(el => el.Process==="process1")
            myvar = x.Shortnum
            console.log(myvar)
        })
}
```

My issue is where I define `myvar` as `shortnum`, it cannot narrow down the query to only `Shortnum`.

If I run this without the `.shortnum` filter it works fine. i.e. `console.log(x)` will return the dictionary where the process is `process1`.

Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
{
    "mydata": [
        {
            "Process": "process1",
            "Shortnum": "00000",
            "Status": 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `x` is an *array*!

Comment: You might want [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter`: this would result the matching object instead of an array.

Comment: You receive an array after the call to filter... . Your May access the first value with x[0].Shortnum ....

Comment: When you have such problem, the best is to look at the precise point either by debugging or by logging the value (`x`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` returns an array. What you want is probably the first (only?) matching object.

You might use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead:

```
let x = data.mydata.find(el => el.Process==="process1")
let myvar = x.Shortnum
console.log(myvar)
```

Comment: This is great thanks, what if i wanted to find the maximum value for my criteria?

Comment: @EcSync then use `Math.max(...data.mydata.filter(el => el.Process==="process1").map(o => o.Shortnum))`